# Cannot use CONFIG_GCC_PLUGINS: your gcc installation does not support plugins

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, debian, gnu-make

I am trying to compile kernel 4.14.* on Debian 12. I have gcc version 12 installed, together with base and plugins packages:

```
gcc
gcc-12
gcc-12-base:amd64
gcc-12-plugin-dev
```

but I get these errors:

```
Cannot use CONFIG_GCC_PLUGINS: your gcc installation does not support plugins, perhaps the necessary headers are missing?
make: *** [scripts/Makefile.gcc-plugins:70: gcc-plugins-check] Error 1
```

full log [here](https://ctxt.io/2/AABQdYo6Ew)

I can compile newer kernel 6.1.* without problems. Is this some incompatibility between the old kernel and newer gcc version ?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you want to fix the **last** error message instead of the **first** one? "This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options."

Comment: @Tsyvarev - so where should I add the `-std=gnu++11` option? I am compiling kernel using `make -j64`.

Comment: The output you show doesn't look like the one when Linux kernel is compiled. You probably need to provide more details about how exactly have you compiled the kernel.